# How to check that string contains letter in any language?

Tags: php, regex, validation, unicode, letter

My current regex is `/^[a-zA-Z]+( [a-zA-Z]+)*$/`. It works for names like:

`John Smith`

Anyway, the site is international and name could be like this, for example:

`Jānis Bērziņš`

It's a valid name, but regex will fail to validate it because of `ā`, `ē` and `š` chars.

The one way would be to type all chars that are allowed, but then the list would be HUGE!

I'm looking for easier way to do that. Maybe black-list instead of white-list approach?

Thanks in any advice!

Comment: Do you need it just for names? If so, white-list approach should do just fine

Comment: You shouldn't be trying to validate names in the first place. They can contain many more symbols besides letters.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use a regex in UTF-8 mode with [the appropriate Unicode character propert(y/ies)](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.unicode.php).

Comment: Something like that. You may want *some* punctuation though (-, ', etc.).

Answer (score 2):

Just replace your character class with the unicode property for letter `\pL`

```
/^\pL+( \pL+)*$/
```

See [here on regular/expressions.info](http://www.regular-expressions.info/unicode.html#prop) an overview of the unicode properties

in my test on [writecodeonline.com](http://writecodeonline.com/php/) this is working

```
$s = "Jānis Bērziņš";
preg_match("/^\\pL+( \\pL+)*$/", $s, $matches);
```

Comment: Well, mentioned `Jānis Bērziņš` fails for that.

Comment: Please change your regex to `/^\pL+( \pL+)*$/uD` so it works as expected.

Comment: @daGrevism in my test its working as is without the `u` modifier, not sure whats causing this.